# can't sync gradle android studio 3.1.4

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio-3.1.4

I installed android studio 3.1.4 with gradle 4.4 but I can't sync it , 
I read all topics about syncing but I get error from all dependencies, I added maven link, mavencentral, change implementation with compile but nothing worked

these are the errors:

> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2.

and this is my gradle.build :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "comcooking.wikiyar.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Is your network connection working? Which repositories did you define in the top level build.gradle file?

Comment: add "aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }" in you gradle file.

Comment: you can use from VPN